# Methods to fill golang nested structure from db

Tags: database, go, struct, nested, fill

Let's say we have a go structures:

```
type Address struct {
  Address string
  Phone string
}

type Person struct {
  Name string
  Addresses []Address
}
```

To fill Person i use this function:

```
func GetPersons() ([]Person, error) {
    fc := []Person{}

    sql := `SELECT name FROM persons`
    rows, err := config.Db.Query(sql)

    if err != nil {
        return fc, err
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next(){
        p := Person{}
        err := rows.Scan(&p.Name)
        if err != nil{
            return fc, err
        }
        fc = append(fc, p)
    }

    return fc, err
}
```

What are methods to fill nested Addresses struct from DB table person_addresses?
I don't need to use any ORM.

Comment: Edit the question to show the schema of persons and person_addresses.

Comment: I know you just said you don't need an orm, but maybe you should consider sqlx?
https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx
It will try to map whatever rows it gets back into structures, based on tags you provide. I'm not sure I'd classify it as an orm, but maybe orm-lite?